# How to query and combine columns with different criteria into one table/view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

**Here's the example:** Lets say I have magazine subscriptions. I have Magazine A, B, C.  Every month I would like to know how many subscribers i've gained, lost, and total per magazine. I would aslo Like to be able to search by month, year.
I would like to display the data in this way:

```
Mag  |Total|New|Lost|
--------------------- 
MagA | 25  | 7 |  1 |
 
MagB | 32  | 3 |  6 |
 
MagC | 65  | 4 |  2 |
```

So here is what I've done:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_MemberCount(@Month INT, @Year INT)
  RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
WITH M AS
(
SELECT
  Mag, MagID, COUNT(M.UserID) 'Count', 'New' AS 'Change'
FROM Members as M JOIN Mags as B
  ON M.MagID = B.MemberID
WHERE Month(M.JoinDate) = @Month 
  AND YEAR(M.Joindate) = @Year 
GROUP BY B.MagID ,B.Mag

UNION ALL

SELECT
  Mag, MagID, COUNT(M.UserID) 'Count', 'Closed' AS 'Change'
FROM Members as M JOIN Mags as B
  ON M.MagID = B.MemberID
WHERE Month(M.CancelDate) = @Month 
  AND YEAR(M.CancelDate) = @Year 
GROUP BY B.MagID, B.Mag
),
PivotData AS
(
SELECT
  MagID, Mag, Change, [Count]
FROM M
)
SELECT MagID, Mag, [New], [Closed]
FROM PivotData
  Pivot (SUM([Count])
   For Change IN ([New], [Closed])) AS P
);
```

I used a union because they criteria for a new subscription and a cancelled subscription are different and this seemed like the most logical way to do it.
The function is to able to simply add year and month and filter the results that way. If i need to automate this further i will probably put it in a stored procedure.

**Is there a better way to obtain the same results?** Or a **different way to have a different search criteria per column?**

*(I know that the code above does not produce the first `Total` column. For that I would create another `UNION ALL` but I wanted to ask the community for suggestions before spending more time on this)*

### Any suggestions or advise is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to simplify the query. The `where` clauses you had in question would be the conditions on which you aggregate.

```
SELECT
  B.Mag
 ,B.MagID 
 ,COUNT(M.USERID)  as Total
 ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Month(M.JoinDate) = @Month AND YEAR(M.Joindate) = @Year THEN 1 END) AS New
 ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Month(M.CancelDate) = @Month AND YEAR(M.CancelDate) = @Year THEN 1 END) AS Cancel
FROM Members as M 
JOIN Mags as B ON M.MagID = B.MemberID
GROUP BY B.MagID,B.Mag
```

Comment: Wow, so simply. Thank you so much! for some reason I had not even thought about case statements.